# iOS: Does writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum compress the origin image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `UImagePickerController` to take a photo from the camera on iOS9. Then I found that using `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` to save the image is different from saving the image using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` at the file size. Code as follow:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {

    if( [picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera ) {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        ALAssetsLibrary *library =  [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)image.imageOrientation completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error ) {
//            NSLog(@"url: %@", assetURL.absoluteString);
            NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
            NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"/tmp.jpg"];
            [data1 writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
            [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
//                CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
                NSLog(@"size1: %lu, size2: %lld", data1.length, rep.size);
            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            }];
        }];
    }
}
```

it prints:

```
2016-09-08 10:10:56.690658 TestPhotoes[6096:2345233] size1: 5549568, size2: 2288036
```

You see, the image file saved by `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` is way much bigger than by `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`. I was wondering what the  `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` did? Does it compress the origin image? How can I save image using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to achieve the same effect, both image file size, and the image quality?

Comment: I change UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) to UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)，the photo size is just a little big than ``writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`` now. Not sure whether it low the quality of the photo or not.